# Fade-In and Out on Images/Screensaver with CSS & Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a screensaver/slideshow that I'm working on. Its meant to loop through the images and fade-in and out using CSS and I'm applying classes using JQuery to achieve that. But the problem I have is that I only constantly loads the first Image and doesn't load the 2nd or any consecutive images.

Here's the **HTML and script**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            var imageTime =30000;
            var autoSwitch = true;
            var fadeSpeed = 500;

            $(".touch-screensaver-container").first().addClass("fade-in");
            $(".touch-screensaver-container").hide();
            $(".fade-in").show();
            if(autoSwitch == true){
                setInterval(nextSlide,5000);
            }

            function nextSlide(){
                $('.fade-in').removeClass('fade-in').addClass('fade-out');
                if($('.fade-out').is(':last-child')){
                    $('.touch-container').first().addClass('fade-in');
                }else {
                    $('.fade-out').next().addClass('fade-in');
                }
                $('.fade-out').removeClass('fade-out');
            }
        });
```

```css
.fade-in {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    }

    @keyframes fadeInOpacity {
       0% { opacity: 0;}
       99% { opacity: 0.99;}
       100% {opacity: 1;}
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeInOpacity {
       0% { opacity: 0;}
       99% { opacity: 0.99;}
       100% { opacity: 1;}
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
       0% { opacity: 1;}
       99% { opacity: 0.01;width: 100%; height: 100%;}
       100% { opacity: 0;width: 0; height: 0;}
    }
    @keyframes fadeOut {
       0% { opacity: 1;}
       99% { opacity: 0.01;width: 100%; height: 100%;}
       100% { opacity: 0;width: 0; height: 0;}
    }

    .fade-out{
       display: block;
       -webkit-animation: fadeOut 1s;
       animation: fadeOut 1s;
       animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

        <nav id="kiosk-navbar" class="kiosk-navbar" role="navigation">
            <div class="kiosk-navbar-language-container">
                <a id="languageSelector" class="btn touch-btn touch-btn-xs primary-btn animated" href="/">
                    <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="kiosk-navbar-image-container">
                <div class="kiosk-navbar-image"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div id="content" class="container-parent kiosk-background">
            <div class="main-content"><div class="screensaver-image-container ">
    
        <div class="touch-container touch-screensaver-container">
            <a class="homeLink" href="/public/selectLanguage"><img class="screensaverImage" id="https://localhost:443/api/public/resource/6f39ad92-5cdb-4ddf-a0f7-41d4d7edbb4b/fetch/image?file=c231789d-3574-4d2d-8a07-a9c52c97dfd7.jpeg" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552974380-6df376868cda?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" /></a>
        </div>
    
    
        <div class="touch-container touch-screensaver-container">
            <a class="homeLink" href="/public/selectLanguage"><img class="screensaverImage" id="https://localhost:443/api/public/resource/6f39ad92-5cdb-4ddf-a0f7-41d4d7edbb4b/fetch/image?file=71924af8-057f-41f8-a2e3-a9ce8017006a.jpeg" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541929347448-1a5788e6178a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

I've spent a couple of days trying to figure it out but unable to do so. Any help would be appreciated. I even thought of added ID to the images but the image links are served by the controller in Spring and displayed using Thymeleaf's for:each, so i dont have anything to provide ID except the link itself.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you used one of the thousands of ready to use slideshow libraries/plugins/demos?

Comment: You used `hide()` on the second image, then never made it show again. Also, the `fade-out` class was removed right after you added it. [Here's](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OqaYeO?editors=1010) a demo.

Comment: You could do the same with [only a fraction of the code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WmYqzm?editors=0110) though.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak I thought about it but we decided against using third party plugins/libraries.

Comment: @Shikkediel that worked like a charm! Thank you :)